# Using variable in for next loop code

Tags: vb.net

I have following code,

```
My.Settings.h301 = TextBox301.Text
My.Settings.h302 = TextBox302.Text
My.Settings.h303 = TextBox303.Text
My.Settings.h304 = TextBox304.Text
My.Settings.h305 = TextBox305.Text
```

I want to convert above code like following;

```
For i = 301 To 305 Step 1
    My.Settings.h & i = TextBox & i.Text
Next
```

So, please provide me correct for next loop code. Thank you.

Comment: Use `My.Settings(h & i)`.

Comment: Doesnt work....

Comment: Thank you. Solved.

Comment: Then another developer will try to improve readability of your code and change name of setting or change name of `TextBox` - and your application will stop working :) Use right tool for the job - `Dictionary` with shared key, where settings can be retrieved for correspondent textbox by the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To pass a string as a control name, you can use: `ParentControl.Controls("ControlName")`.
- To pass a string as an application setting name, you can use: `My.Settings("SettingName")`.

Hence, your code should look something like the following:

```
For i = 301 To 305 Step 1
    My.Settings("h" & i.ToString) = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i.ToString).Text
Next
```

Please note that if the parent of your textboxes is not the form, you'll need to replace `Me` with the parent control name.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

If this is a WinForm project, all of the controls are included in the form's Controls collection, which is accessible by name, like this:

```
For x As Integer = 300 to 400
Me.Controls("My.Settings.h" & i.ToString()).height = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i.ToString()).Text
Next
```

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed : It would also be good telling him what it _actually is_ too. -- @Zenoheld : `My.Settings` is a class/object used to handle, store, and retrieve settings specific to the application. Read more on the [**MSDN documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613.aspx).