# Accessing buttons names using variables

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In visual basic I want to be able to access a button's name using the number stored in a variable.
For example if I have 24 buttons that are all named 'Button' with the numbers 1, 2, 3... 22, 23, 24 after it. If I want to then change the text in the first eight buttons how would I do that.

Here's my example to help show what I mean:

```
    For i = 1 to 8
        Button(i).text = "Hello"
    Next
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Control Arrays in VB .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299435/how-to-create-control-arrays-in-vb-net)

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41412984/4934172)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For index As Integer = 1 To 8
   CType(Me.Controls("Button" & index.ToString().Trim()),Button).Text = "Hello"
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solutions so far will fail if the Buttons are not **directly contained** by the Form itself.  What if they are in a different container?  You could simple change "Me" to "Panel1", for instance, but that doesn't help if the Buttons are spread across **multiple containers**.

To make it work, regardless of the Buttons locations, use the `Controls.Find()` method with the "searchAllChildren" option:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ctlName As String
    Dim matches() As Control
    For i As Integer = 1 To 8
        ctlName = "Button" & i
        matches = Me.Controls.Find(ctlName, True)
        If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is Button Then
            Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(matches(0), Button)
            btn.Text = "Hello #" & i
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ and you're good to go:

```
Dim yourButtonArray = yourForm.Controls.OfType(of Button).ToArray
' takes all controls whose Type is Button
For each button in yourButtonArray.Take(8)
    button.Text = "Hello"
Next
```

Or

```
Dim yourButtonArray = yourForm.Controls.Cast(of Control).Where(
    Function(b) b.Name.StartsWith("Button")
    ).ToArray
' takes all controls whose name starts with "Button" regardless of its type
For each button in yourButtonArray.Take(8)
    button.Text = "Hello"
Next
```

In any case, `.Take(8)` will iterate on the first 8 items stored inside `yourButtonArray`