# Accessing checkboxes with variables

Tags: c#, winforms

I have asked this question previously but for VB.NET here:

[Accessing buttons names using variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41557129/accessing-buttons-names-using-variables)

Now I want to do the same but in C# and with CheckBoxes so for example, if I have 31 check boxes labeled "CheckBox1...CheckBox31" I could do :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    (CheckBox + i).Enabled = false;
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Try out and see what you get

Comment: Ok, I tried it and it gave the error 'CheckBox' is a type, which is not valid in the given context"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
    ((CheckBox)this.Controls[$"CheckBox{i}"]).Enabled = false;
 }
```

Comment: You probably should use `(CheckBox)this.Controls[...]` instead of `this.Controls[...] as CheckBox` because `as` returns `null` if the Element doesn't exist, as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/132467/8649828)

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a `List<CheckBox>` or an array of all checkboxes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkbox_array.Length; i++) {
    checkbox_array[i].Enabled = false;
}
```

**EDIT**: I might be a bit late, but if you put all `CheckBoxes` in a `GroupBox` (wich I really recommend doing if you have *soo* many checkboxes), you can just loop trough all the controls in that groupbox like this:

```
foreach (CheckBox cbx in gbxCheckBoxes.Controls) {
    cbx.Enabled = true;
}
```

or like this: (if you only need to enable them)

```
gbxCheckBoxes.Enabled = false;
```

(`gbxCheckBoxes` is the `GroupBox` I was talking about)